# maven rebuilds modules because of auto-generated files from thrift, any way to only generate changed files?

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin, thrift

EDIT: skip to the last sentence for the correct relevant question

i am building a project with this maven command:

```
-am -DskipTests=true -pl myModule install
```

the project is very large and the module has a lot of dependencies, and for some reason they get recompiled even though they are unchanged,
i am getting this message for a lot of modules:

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
```

this is my build tag:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

i am using maven 3.5.0

why do the dependent modules get recognized as changed?

edit:using  michaldo's advice

i discovered a dependency module that a lot of Stale source detected
on auto generated .java files created from thrift,

the question now becomes: how do i instruct maven/thrift, not to generate .java files for unchanged thrift sources?

Comment: 1. Your problem is that maven compiler plugin detects false source change and recompiles module without need. Please be strict and update question title: your issue is unnecessary recompilation, not build time in general. 2. Find module which is being recompiled unnecessary and call within `mvn compile -X` (or test-compile). In flood of debug messages find which file is being detected as changed and continue investigation

Comment: Hi, I see you are now much closer to success. However it is still hard to help someone who didn't say what he does :). If you use Thrift Maven Plugin, make sure you use checkStaleness  parameter. https://github.com/dtrott/maven-thrift-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/thrift/maven/AbstractThriftMojo.java#L174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

michaldo's comments solved my problem,
after resolving all unnecessary code generation from the thrift plugin, the build is much faster

the critical bit is to add checkStaleness parameter to the configuration:

```
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-thrift-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <thriftExecutable>${thrift.exe}</thriftExecutable>
                *<checkStaleness>true</checkStaleness>*
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Great! According to SO practice, answer should contain critical fragment of  thrift plugin configuration. It allows others easy applying your findings